# Implicitly excluding certain directories in mu4e queries

Tags: mu4e

Is there an option to exclude certain directories from a mu4e search
without stating this explicitly in the search string?  For example,
could I have

```
date:today
```

exclude `/archive` so long as the option is active?
I know about the possiblility of putting a `.noindex` in the directory
to be excluded, but I would like to be *able* to search it too, without doing a whole chore.